# Как запустить приложение AngularJS в подгруженном в DIV html?

Tags: ajax, javascript, angularjs

Имеется небольшое приложение на ангуляре (директива), которое прекрасно работает на одиночной странице. Но вот если эту страницу загрузить аяксом в DIV, ангуляр даже не запускается.

Чтобы упростить сделал на фидле два примерчика:
Вот так не работает: http://jsfiddle.net/ivahaev/mnv2mqfp/1/

А вот так вполне работает:
http://jsfiddle.net/ivahaev/mnv2mqfp/2/

Пробовал загружать ангуляр и контоллеры в разном порядке - все без толку. То, что в родительском HTML - исполняется. Что в дочернем - нифига.

И да, я понимаю, что это в концепцию ангуляра не складывается. Но я постепенно перевожу свое приложение. Не могу все сразу сделать.

Ах да, вопрос! Как запустить-то? :)

P.S. Решение найдено!
http://jsfiddle.net/ivahaev/mnv2mqfp/3/
Мануал тут:
https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/bootstrap
**Manual Initialization**

Comment: а чего бы вам эту страницу как темплейт не загружать ?

Comment: А потому что эта страница - часть большого приложения и генерируется на сервере

Comment: ну и запрашивать темплейт с сервера.

Comment: Перепишите вопрос по формату сервиса.

Answer (score 2):

Это делается через [$compile](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$compile):

```js
angular.module('myapp', [])
  .directive('replace', replace);


replace.$inject = ['$compile'];

function replace($compile) {
  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    link: function($scope, $elem) {
      var html = "<input type='text' ng-model='username'>{{username}}";
      $elem.append($compile(html)($scope));
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="myapp">
  Parent content here
  <br>
  <hr>Subsidiary content:
  <div replace></div>
</div>
```

Если используется форма с [ngModelController](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/ngModel.NgModelController) и необходимо привязать scope динамически добавленного элемента формы, к примеру, input (чтобы задействовать нативный валидатор):

```js
angular.module('myapp', [])
  .directive('replace', replace)
  .directive('username', username);


replace.$inject = ['$compile'];

function replace($compile) {
  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    link: function($scope, $elem) {
      var html = "<input type='text' name='username' ng-model='username' username required>{{username}}";
      $elem.append($compile(html)($scope));
    }
  }
}

function username() {
  return {
    require: 'ngModel',
    restrict: 'A',
    link: function($scope, $elem, $attrs, $ctrl) {
      $scope.form.$addControl($ctrl);
    }
  }
}
```

```css
input {
  display: block;
}
input.ng-invalid.ng-touched {
  background-color: #FA787E;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.15/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="myapp">
  Parent content here
  <br>
  <hr>Subsidiary content:

  <form name="form" novalidate>
    <div replace><!--добавляемый элемент формы--></div>
    <span ng-show="form.username.$touched && form.username.$error.required">Username is empty.</span> 

    <input type='password' name='pass' ng-model='pass' required>{{pass}}
    <span ng-show="form.pass.$touched && form.pass.$error.required">Password is empty.</span> 
  </form>
</div>
```